# How to switch languages on all desktops in Windows using Caps Lock?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language, capslock

lswitch fails (it works only on the first desktop). Running a copy of hacked lswitch on each desktop also fails.

Punto switcher seems too big and intrusive for the task (and old version doesn't have Caps Lock option)

Comment: Not an answer, but you could do this with an AutoHotKey script pretty easily I'd think.

Comment: If there is a way to reliably switch input layout using Win32API <b>on multiple desktops</b>, lswitch could be easily modified to work well.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple desktops"?

Comment: Ability to have separate set of windows, associated with "Desktop" objects and to switch between desktops quickly. 

It is provided by CreateDesktop/SwitchDesktop Win32API functions (Not to be confused with WindowStations).

First, "Default" desktop is the sole default desktop and the one where interactive services put their windows.

Others can be created only with third-party programs like "HKM".

Comment: @Vi, care to elaborate about the use case? (I have no idea how to do that, I'm just curious why you need that).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Caps Lock Switch](http://chuchuva.com/prog/capsswitch.zip)

Comment: Works only on the desktop where I started it. Mangles keyboard and causes delays and beeps when attempting to start on other desktop.

Have you actually tested it on multiple desktops (that are managed with SwitchDesktop WinAPI function)

Comment: @Vi No, not really - sorry.